# MySQL query sent successfully, yet database field stays empty

Tags: php, mysql, database

The following 2 queries are the result of an echo in php:

```
UPDATE glymping_userdata
SET current_location_gps = '51.9171115;4.484812'
WHERE id = 1
```

and

```
UPDATE glymping_user_has_appointments
SET status = 'enroute',
start_location_gps = '51.9171115;4.484812'
WHERE userId = 1
AND appointmentId = 47
```

Both queries work when entered manually in the database and all fields are filled correctly. When I let the php file run the queries, the queries are like shown above, but the "start_location_gps" and the "current_location_gps" are empty.

The values in the queries are strings and the database fields are a varchar(30). Yet the fields in the database are empty.

The location value is received from a post method.

Does anyone knows what I am forgetting or doing wrong?

EDIT:

php example

```
public function SendQuery($query)
{
    $results = $this->mysqli->query($query);
    return $results;
}

public function UpdateUserLocation($currentLocationGps)
{
    $query = "UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."userdata
                SET current_location_gps = '{$currentLocationGps}'
                WHERE id = ".$this->userId;
    //echo $query;
    $this->db->SendQuery($query);
}
```

Comment: Where's your PHP code?

Comment: Which mysql api do you use? The old mysql_* functions or mysqli_* or pdo?

Comment: Sorry, added some php code. The added code shows the function creating the query and the function sending the query

Comment: so what's the return value of the query? also, does the query run if you try it outside PHP context?

Comment: Have you double checked that `$currentLocationGps` isn't empty when it's being passed? Where does that value come from?

Comment: when you echo $query, it looks exactly like your example? Also, are you sure connection was successfully created?

Comment: you should always check your return values... something like throwing an exception if the query returns false. In PDO, there would be `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` to do that for you. in mysqli, you have to do it yourself afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code doesn't check the return value of mysqli_query; the query might fail "silently". It could also be that the query does not affect any records in the database becaue of wrong values in the WHERE clause.
Try it with

```
if ( !$this->db->SendQuery($query) ) {
  // query failed: syntax error, connection lost, access denied,duplicate entries, ...
  trigger_error($this->mysqli->error);
}
else {
  if ( 0 < $this->mysqli->affected_rows ) {
    // WHERE clause doesn't match any record, no values changed, ...
    trigger_error('no rows affected');
  }
}
```

Your query might also be prone to sql injections, please check http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: if you - for testing purposes - replace `trigger_error` by `die` does it show anything? Maybe also add an unconditional `echo 'Debug: ', htmlspecialchars($query);` before the SendQuery-line to verify that the function is called in the first place...